# understanding Windows 10 file access permissions

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I took ownership of a system file and its parent folder:

[image]

But still when I try to rename it I dont posses the correct permissions?

[image]

Same for Powershell:

[image]

In some cases I was able to delete the file but not rename it.

I am user Martin and are owner and everybody has full access to the file but still explorer and powershell prevent write access.

**How do Windows file permissions work?**

Comment: this is because on this file exist [`S-1-19-512-4096`](https://github.com/long123king/tokenext/blob/master/tokenext/TokenExt.h#L1503) - *Trust Label Lite(PPL) PsProtectedSignerWindows(5)* - look [Why can’t I restore files even when I have backup/restore privileges enabled?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2016/12/12/why-cant-i-restore-files-even-when-i-have-backuprestore-privileges-enabled/)

Comment: also [Cannot write on WindowsApps directories and restore files](https://superuser.com/questions/1039116/cannot-write-on-windowsapps-directories-and-restore-files) and [undocumented SID structure on windows 10 S-1-19-512-4096](https://superuser.com/questions/1039311/undocumented-sid-structure-on-windows-10-s-1-19-512-4096) - this is exactly your case

Comment: we can got this label when query with `PROCESS_TRUST_LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`

Comment: wow... Security through obscurity -.- Thank you! Why dont you post it as an answer and I flag it accepted?

Comment: well what makes it secure is not the fact that you don't know the key, the S-1-19-51-4096. its just undocumented what the key opens.